# Are devas similar or dissimilar to human beings?

Tags: gods, philosophy, human

Are the devas very similar to humans beings in most aspects, and are they like the material beings and objects that we encounter in daily experience?

Or are the devas very dissimilar to human beings in most aspects, and almost completely unlike the objects of daily experience, although vaguely similar to human beings in a few key aspects?

Or are they something else?

Comment: the bodies of the devas are the subtle body. they do not possess the outer kosha.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Can you give me the citations for this view from Scripture or any scholars?